# Please any ideas for installing settings.apk to system without root on 4.4.3?

Tags: rooting, adb, default-applications, terminal, twrp

<sup>I will answer any questions you have for me....but I am just in need of an answer to the question as posted</sup>

I cannot access the settings on my device, as the settings app is not showing on the installed system applist.

Simply put, it seems the `setting.apk` must be replaced to save the phone.

```
non rooted
kitkat os 4.4.3 
sgs4g
no usb hub working on unit
no recovery working
no settings menu access 
(therefor, no dev settings menu either)
```

i have :
good full twrp recovery backup
good generic flash .image
(recovry can be set up once root is achieved)

Thus:

I have:
good apks/apps to get root access cable free
(but this can only happen when I am able to install apps from unknown sources)

I look forward to your comments

Thank you

and thanks Izzy for the suggestions

Comment: you said : `but this can only happen when I am able to install apps from unknown sources` - why you can't ? do you touch `Unknown Sources` for install? i can't underestand what you want exactly :-?

Comment: my problem right now i just need settings menu to work, which it does not.... due to the settings app not showing on the installed system applist

Comment: "i think",without root you can't.it's better to flash a rom only.

Comment: i can not flash...as noted in body of question; "no recovery working, no root, no usb hub". i simply need to see if anyone knows a way at all to install or enable the settings app, cause it may just be disabled

Comment: scenario ;  flashed a rom and after all settled lost bootload recovery twrp somehow, lost root, and no settings menu.... and to top it off the usb micro hub does not work.  what would you do in this case ?

Comment: i have one idea, if you can get access on `number > keypad` then you can use this code's for example : `*#*#7780#*#*` or `*2767*3855#` for factory reset or full reset.maybe it can help."but maybe..."

Comment: Suggesting a little more, as this time it got much clearer: If the settings app is not visible, it might simply be disabled (should not happen usually, but it might). If you've got a file explorer, you could check (`/system/apps` is usually the place it resides in). In that case, there are ADB commands to re-enable it or, worst case, a factory-reset should restore it. // Btw: If that turns out to be the case, that was a classical [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/66377/192154) :)

Comment: okay thanks Izzy for joining.  and yes in conment above from 6 hours ago i stated it was possibly disabled .... i am ready to run some commands in term if you have something i can run.  please please. itd be great

Comment: M4T -  thanks i have been attempting all kinds of codes, but I get no reply when executed.. maybe something reaching out to cell network settings in the UI cause its blank as soon as code entry is completed (dialer digits dissapear but nothing happens). anyt other ideas...throw it my way...i am hoping the app is disabled and i can enable it..., thank you sir

Comment: hey Izzy,  you got me there..been dealing with this XY my entire life.... my apologies and nice link there... i will attempt to persue the proper agenda and better help others assist me. thanks again